# Input command misunderstood in os.path.join

Tags: python, directory, pygame

I have a line of code, which links a specific folder and file to a variable.

```
face_1 = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("mc\female\face", "f_f_1.png"))
```

Unfortunately, it reads the `mc\female\face` as `mc **\f**emale **\f**ace`, reading the inputs of `\f` instead of a folder director. Is there a way to make it so it doesn't read it as the above without changing the folder names?

Comment: If you are going to use `os.path.join`, use it fully: `os.path.join("mc", "female", "face", "f_f_1.png")`, and let it deal with directory separators.

Comment: Or at least mark your string as raw: `r"mc\female\face"`

Comment: How about `mc\\female\\face`, "f_f_1.png"? note the double slashes.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
face_1 = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("mc\\female\\face", "f_f_1.png"))
```

You should consider using the `Path` module from `pathlib`, it will be easier to concatenate paths.

```
from pathlib import Path

female_base_root = Path("mc\\female\\face")
female_base_one = female_base_root.joinpath("f_f_1.png")
# The full path is now "mc\\female\\face\\f_f_1.png"
female_face_image = pygame.image.load(female_base_one)
```